# remove images after cloning the images

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem for my slider to append the image less than current image. I'm using something like this:

```
var m = $('#main');
m.find('img:lt(3)').clone().remove().appendTo(m);
```

If I use just appendTo(): This won't be appended

`m.find('img:lt(3)').appendTo(m);`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wd38/)

As in demo it is appended but I want to remove previous image.

Comment: But I can see the `appended images` in your `fiddle`

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: I want to append the image and remove the first images which are appended.... thanks for editing my question as my network problem was occorring....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
var m = $('#main');
m.find('img:lt(3)').appendTo(m);
```

When you use `appendTo` with existing elements it doesn't clone them - it moves them.  So cloning and removing the originals is not required :)

**[Working jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8Wd38/1/)**

Comment: So I need to use clone().remove().appendTo()

Comment: Can you show more code then?  The fact that it's inside a click handler should not make any difference.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Me neither - I suspect there may be more to the issue than we've been shown.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see anything wrong with the jsfiddle I posted and that code does *exactly* what you have asked.  Can you explain what is wrong with *my* linked example?